# Building an android camera application

Tags: java, android, android-camera, runtimeexception

Trying to create an android application to record video and capture images. I've followed the tutorials thus far with some success however I must have a lack of knowledge about the android sdk to not be able to get around this issue. No doubt I will feel stupid once someone figures this out but I'm here to learn in the end.

Here is the MainActivity.java

```
package example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public MainActivity(Context context) {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

/** Check if this device has a camera */
public boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}

/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Here is the CameraPreview.java

```
package example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/** A basic Camera preview class */
public class CameraPreview extends MainActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback mPicture;
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private SurfaceHolder holder;

public void setContentView(int activity_camera) {}
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";

public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here

    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    if (pictureFile == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
        return;
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

public void onClick() {
    // Add a listener to the Capture button
    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0){
            // get an image from the camera
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        }
    });
}

public SurfaceHolder getHolder() {
    return holder;
}

public void setHolder(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    this.holder = holder;
}
}
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="example.myapplication" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and the logcat

```
Process: example.myapplication, PID: 20671
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{example.myapplication/example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class example.myapplication.MainActivity; no empty constructor
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2514)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class installation04.myapplication.MainActivity; no empty constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The stack trace is pretty explicit. `can't instantiate class installation04.myapplication.MainActivity; no empty constructor`. You are extending `AppCompatActivity`, which has an empty constructor. You are not providing an empty constructor to your `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things that need to be sorted:

1. Please remove all constructors from classes that extend `Activity`. - Activities do not work this way. Please look read how [Activity Life cycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) works.
2. Please add the `CameraPreview` activity to your manifest as well.

Answer (score 1):

delete MainActivity constructor

```
public MainActivity(Context context) {
}
```

Please read carefully the stacktrace:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{example.myapplication/example.myapplication.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class
>   example.myapplication.MainActivity; no empty constructor

Answer (score 0):

You have created constructor in your Activity. Remove the constructor from your Activities and use the Lifecycle callbacks.
As per android guidelines you should not create constructor in the Activity classes since android OS creates object of Activity classes and it use the default empty constructor of the class to create object.